# Why does the queen have only 10 unique positions in chessboards covering?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, heuristics

In the chessboards covering problem

> The covering problem is that 1 king, 1 queen, 2 knights, 2 bishops, 2
>   rooks can threat the all 64 squares. Where should they be?

in order to reduce the search space, we can limit the queen's possible places to only 10.

> Getting the job done would require significant pruning. Our first idea was to remove symmetries. Accounting for orthogonal and diagonal symmetries left only ten distinct positions for the queen, shown in Figure

[image: Queen's possible places]

Ok. I don't understand this.

Why queen's possible places can be limited like that?

Why symmetries can be considered for limiting queen's places? So in the above figure, queen being placed at the bottom left corner is the same as it being placed at the bottom right corner? Why is that?

Comment: I would not vote to close... this is actually a very instructive problem in terms of symmetry in data structures.

Comment: for those who vote for closing, please give a reason in comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the symmetry is only valid for the first piece placed.  Once a piece is placed on the board, you lose some or all of the symmetry:  the board no longer looks the same when mirrored or rotated.

The problem you post appears to assume that the queen is the first piece placed.  For the specific problem, this makes sense, since the queen can cover more of the board than any other, so it may reduce the work required to place the remaining pieces.  However, the symmetry aspect is similar for whatever piece you place first:  only the first piece can take advantage of the full board symmetry.

---

Note that, once the first piece is placed, there may still be some residual symmetry, that can save additional time.  For instance, if the first piece is placed along the diagonal, you can still mirror along that diagonal.  However, this residual symmetry would take more complex (and error-prone) code to take advantage of...

Answer (score 4):

If you rotate the board by 90, 180, or 270 degrees, you end up with exactly the same problem.  Similarly, you move a queen to it's mirror-image position (across a diagonal, or across the middle of the board horizontally or vertically) the solution turns out to be exactly the same as if you didn't.

To understand the diagonal symmetry:

Try placing a queen in the lower-left corner, solve the problem, then place the queen in the upper-right corner and solve the problem.  You will see that the solutions are exactly the same.

To understand the rotational symmetry:

Try placing the queen in the lower-left corner, solve the problem, then move to the lower-right corner.  The solution again is exactly the same.

You may wish to do this with a smaller board, say 4x4 or 6x6, so that there are fewer solution steps so that it's easier to grasp the symmetry.

Comment: But when rotating, can we also eliminate others' (such as king's, bishop's) positions?

Comment: let me simplify the problem. Assume now I find a solution, say, king is at position A, queen is at position B, then King-A and Queen-B is a solution. But now if I change queen's position to C, where C is the symmetry position of B, do you think King-A and Queen-C is still the same solution?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? The covering problem is that 1 king, 1 queen, 2 knights, 2 bishops, 2 rooks can threat the all 64 squares. Where should they be?

Comment: I don't understand all of the rules of the simulation, but I can say with confidence:  If you find your positions A and B, you can apply any combination of board rotations and/or mirrorings across a diagonal or across the middle of the board to BOTH A AND B, and you will end up with a new, valid solution.

Comment: Ah... so it's a variant of the N-Queen problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle  See my previous comment.  Yes, you can apply the **same** transformation or series of transformations to **each** position from one solution and arrive at a new, valid solution.

Comment: Ok, could you please tell me then do king or bishop or knight or rook also have similar symmetry positions? Are those symmetry positions the same as indicated in the figure?

Comment: Part of my understanding is that to this problem, if the cover area of queen being at A and area of being at B are exactly the same, then I can say A and B are symmetry. But in the figure, it seems not.

Comment: In general, the symmetry is only valid for the first piece placed; the problem you post appears to assume that this is the queen.  However, if you placed the king first, the initial chessboard symmetry would apply to it, instead.

Comment: @comingstorm ok, what you said makes sense. Please explain more if I place the king first. Will the king's places are also limited to exactly the same as queens (shown as the figure)

Comment: Yes.  The reason is, placing a piece will spoil (or at least limit) the initial symmetry for later pieces.

Comment: @comingstorm so you mean whatever piece I place, as long as it is the first one, the symmetry positions for it will be all the same as shown in the figure?

Comment: Yes, the same board symmetry applies to whatever piece is placed first.  Once the piece is placed, you lose some or all of the symmetry:  the board no longer looks the same when mirrored or rotated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11072/discussion-between-jackson-tale-and-comingstorm)